# Atomics Functions of CVXPY in Pyomo

Tags: optimization, pyomo, cvxpy

I am trying to translate a problem modeled in CVXPY into Pyomo.
Currently I have the doubt of how the atoms functions can be carried out in pyomo, in particular the cp.pos function
I used it to declare a variable:

```
variable_3 = cp.pos(variable_2-variable_1)
```

So that the result is positive numbers of the difference

Is there a way to do this in pyomo?

Comment: This depends on what you are doing with `variable_3` and cvxpy has this info to figure it out. Without this info, it's hard to recommend something.

Comment: I recommend you a simple reformulation for that: `cp.pos(var2-var1)` is the same that `max(var2-var1,0)` and that can be reformulated as two constraints: `var3 >= var2-var1` and `var3>=0`

Comment: Just for statement, this is not be exactly the same, but an approximation. Since your constraining `var3` to be greater or equal, therefore, `var3` might take some other values depending on your O.F. direction and others constraints.